# Anyone can use Settings.settings file in C# AOT?

Tags: c#, .net

Seems Settings.settings can not work in C# AOT.

I found you can use

```
Properties.Settings.Default.My_Key
```

to get the value of My_Key in Settings.settings.

but when you use

```
Properties.Settings.Default.My_Key = "abc"
```

to set the value, the program will close with an error "can't find My_Key".

This issue only occurs during AOT publishing, and there is no similar problem with JIT publishing.

Comment: There are no `Settings` in .NET Core. AOT only works with .NET Core. `Properties.Settings.Default` was only used in .NET Framework. The values were stored in an application's app.config or web.config XML files. In .NET Core, config files were [replaced by the configuration middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) that can read settings from *multiple* sources, including JSON files, environment variables, the command line, databases etc. The default setup when in ASP.NET Core or the generic host loads from JSON files, environment and CLI params

Comment: The only way `Properties.Settings.Default` can work in .NET Core is to explicitly add the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` compatibility package, create the necessary XML files by hand *AND* make sure they're published with the correct names. These files no longer receive special treatment which means VS or `dotnet build` no longer copy them to the output and rename them to match the application's name

Comment: A better idea would be to *not* use Settings, store the settings you need in `appsettings.json` and retrieve them through IConfiguration or Options objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So if I use AOT I use .NET Core, if I use JIT the vs2022 will use .NET Framework? I just added and removed <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>, I don't know vs2022 changed the platform.

Comment: No it doesn't. That's not what I said. Your code wouldn't even compile unless you added the legacy `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package. If you do want to use `web.config` or `app.config` you must ensure that the files are copied to the final destination yourself. Does your publishing or production folder contain any config files?

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need to get settings? If you want to get dynamic property, you can use appsettings.

```
string settingValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingName"];
```

Comment: Yes, I use appsettings now, but I still don't know how to write key=>value into the appsettings file.